# Name Attribute of Clicked Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the Clicked element using java script

my code :

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var elementname =e.?????? ;
        alert(elementname);

    }, false);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
     alert($(e.target).attr('name'))
});
```

Comment: thats DO the TRICK!!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: any hint on how can I change the value with that element name?

Answer (score 1):

If the clicked element has a `name` attribute that has a defined meaning for the element, e.g. in an `input` element, then the following suffices:

```
    var elementname = e.target.name;
```

If it has a made-up `name` attribute, as in `<div name=foo>` (where the attribute has no defined meaning and no effect, beyond being placed in the `attributes` property of the element node), then use

```
    var elementname = e.target.getAttribute('name');
```

In both cases, you should probably check the result for not being `undefined` before doing anything else with it.

So you don’t need jQuery for this.

I have assumed that you want the `name` attribute of the clicked element, since this is what the question title says. The wording in the question body (“How can I get the Clicked element”) and the variable name `elementname` suggest to me that you might actually been asking how to get the tag name, such as `DIV` or `H1` or `BODY`. That would be a different question; then you should use `var elementname = e.target.tagName`.

Answer (score 1):

i tried code to get clicked element name.

in jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).click(function(e){
    alert( $(e.target).attr('name'));
    });
});
```

for more please go to link. http://jsfiddle.net/amkYz/

in javascript:

```
document.onclick = myClickHandler;
    function myClickHandler(e) {
     alert(e.target.name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your post as jQuery so I'd go with:

```
$('*').click(function(){
    alert($(this).get(0).tagName)
});
```